# why onblur is not properly firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect that the window/tab is currently in focus or not.My code is working well to detect the focus lose when i am switching between tabs but it fails if the current window is covered by some application(music player or any other software).I know focus checking can be done in many ways but i am interested to have a solution based on my code.Can anybody tells me why the following code is not working as expected ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var hidden, change, vis = {
            hidden: "visibilitychange",
            mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
            webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
            msHidden: "msvisibilitychange",
            oHidden: "ovisibilitychange" /* not currently supported */
        };             
    for (hidden in vis) {
        if (vis.hasOwnProperty(hidden) && hidden in document) {
            change = vis[hidden];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (change)
        document.addEventListener(change, onchange);
    else if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) // IE 9 and lower
        document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange
    else
        window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

    function onchange (evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt.type == "focus" || evt.type == "focusin")
           window_focus = true;
        else if (evt.type == "blur" || evt.type == "focusout")
           window_focus = false;
        else        
           window_focus = this[hidden] ? false : true;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [Using the Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API).

> When compared with registering onblur/onfocus handlers on the window, a key difference is that a page does not become hidden when another window is made active and the browser window loses focus. A page only becomes hidden when the user switches to a different tab or minimizes the browser window.

Your code should work as you expect in browsers not supporting Visibility API only.